# Can I convert docx to PDF while also encrypting it at the same time?

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, apache-poi

I'm currently converting **docx to pdf**, then **encrypting the pdf**. Here is my code:

```
    //Convert
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inStream);
    PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, outStream, options);

    //Encrypt
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\uploads\\Resume.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("C:\\uploads\\ResumeEncrypt.pdf"));
    stamper.setEncryption("hello123".getBytes(), "hello".getBytes(),
            PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    stamper.close();

    reader.close();
```

By doing this I am getting 2 files.

What is happening is first I converted the Resume.docx to Resume.pdf, then encrypted the  Resume.pdf to ResumeEncrypt.pdf, resulting to 2 files
This is the example - [image: 2 files]

But I want only one file, that is already converted and encrypted.

This is the example of what I want - [image: only 1 file]

Is it possible to  get a single file after converting  and encrypting ?

Comment: Can't you delete the unwanted file?

Comment: I can do that but I want more efficient way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try use ByteArrayInputStream, give convert pdf.

I made something similar few days ago. Convert Base64 to Gzip and unzip to xml in stream if you want i can give you that code like tip.

So maaybe you can base on this code

```
//Convert Based64, unzip to xml in stream (strLista is list of Base64 bytes
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(strLista.getBytes());
          try(InputStream reader = Base64.getMimeDecoder().wrap(in)){
          try (GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(reader)) {
          try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
            int readGis = 0;
            while ((readGis = gis.read(buff)) > 0)
                out.write(buff, 0, readGis);
```